Error: Failed to collect page data from api/blogs/[blogId]
Getting errors on vercel deployment:
Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/blogs/[blogId]
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1268:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'
}

Here's the code of api/blogs/[blogId]/page.jsx:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { db } from "@/app/lib/db";

export async function DELETE(req, context) {
  try {
    const { params } = context;

    await db.blog.delete({
      where: {
        id: params.blogId,
      },
    });

    return new Response(null, { status: 204 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { mesage: "could not delete blog" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

export async function PATCH(req, context) {
  try {
    const { params } = context;
    const body = await req.json();

    await db.blog.update({
      where: {
        id: params.blogId,
      },
      data: {
        title: body.title,
        content: body.content,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(
      { mesage: "blog updated successfully" },
      { status: 200 }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { mesage: "could not update blog" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

export async function GET(req, context) {
  try {
    const { params } = context;

    const blog = await db.blog.findFirst({
      where: {
        id: params.blogId,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(blog, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { mesage: "could not get blog details" },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

here's app/lib/db file:
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient();
};

const prisma = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton();

export default prisma;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prismaGlobal = prisma;

export const db = prisma;

here's UI of [id] page:
import { db } from "@/app/lib/db";
import BackButton from "@/components/ui/BackButton";
import Image from "next/image";

async function getBlog(id) {
  const res = await db.blog.findFirst({
    where: {
      id: id,
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
      title: true,
      content: true,
      createdAt: true,
    },
  });

  return res;
}

const BlogDetailsPage = async ({ params }) => {
  const blog = await getBlog(params.id);

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen p-6 bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg">
      <BackButton />

      <div className="my-8">
        <h1
          className="text-3xl font-bold text-gray-800 mb-4"
          style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}
        >
          {blog?.title}
        </h1>

        <div className="relative w-screen -mx-6">
          <Image
            src="/assets/images/title1.svg"
            alt="separator 1"
            layout="responsive"
            width={1000}
            height={100}
            className="w-full"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="flex justify-between text-base text-gray-500 mb-4">
          <span>
            Пост был создан {new Date(blog?.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}
          </span>
        </div>

        <div className="relative w-screen -mx-6">
          <Image
            src="/assets/images/title2.svg"
            alt="separator 2"
            layout="responsive"
            width={1000}
            height={100}
            className="w-full"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="text-gray-700">
          <div style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap" }}>{blog?.content}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogDetailsPage;

After research some people saying it might be because of file extension.
Previously it was page.js for me. Then i tried to rename it into page.jsx. Didn't help yet, but i just in case here's tsconfig.json file extensions:
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.jsx"
  ],

UPDATE
i resolved this problem by adding "postinstall": "prisma generate && npm run build" in scripts of package.json.

Can you share your code here "@/app/lib/db"

sure, i added to question

everything looks ok in the db file imo, can you share your UI code for the blog page? (the one use blogId api)

got you, i just added this code

Rename your api/blogs/[blogId]/page.jsx: to api/blogs/[blogId]/route.js:

sure, but as mentioned in this question, it was initially as route.js. Rn i changed as you said it didn't fix the problem:
vercel's saying:
> Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /api/blogs/[blogId]
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1268:15
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'Error'

Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1


@sahilatahar i added "**/*.js" in tsconfig but still getting this error. npm run build tells everything is fine.

@QFaZoPlay What is error type: ... ?

@sahilatahar  hi, i just resolved this issue, look at the update of this question. But thanks so much for help, dude, and The Teabag Coder as well
